# Android emulator to communicate with pc emulator running on

Tags: android, http, networking, httpclient

I have an application that I will run on two separate emulators.

This application uses httpclient to communicate to the server application, that I will run on the same computer as the emulators are running.

"localhost" for the android emulator wont work as local would be the emulator itself.  The computer will not be connected to a laptop.

Which address should I specify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the IP 10.0.2.2 from within the Android emulator to connect to the local machine.  See [Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) on the Android developer site.